# definite integral in matlab?

Tags: calculus, integration, matlab

I have just started learning how to solve definite integrals in matlab, and from the documentation, I picked up this example:

$\int^{\infty}_{0}(e^{-x^2} )dx$ 
but when I run it in my matlab, I get the error:
"The expression to the left of the equals sign is not a valid target for an assignment." (the equals after x, and the second dot after 0 are underlined in red)

what is wrong with this? int() works for me when I try indefinite integrals, but not for this.

Comment: If you're using Matlab, don't look at the documentation for the MuPAD version of `int`. There's a [warning about this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/int.html) right at the top of the page. [This is the page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/int.html) you want. Or just type `help int` or `doc int`.

Comment: @horchler but what if I want to do numeric integration with two variables and some parameters?
for instance,

fun = @(x,c) 1./(x.^3-2*x-c);
q = integral(@(x)fun(x,5),0,2)

but this is for one variable and a parameter

Comment: This sounds like a completely different question and it's more programming related. I'd suggest asking at [StackOverflow.com/Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab) and showing all of the code for what you're trying.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write:

```
syms x;

int(exp(-x^2),x,0,inf)
```

The numerical value should be `pi^(1/2)/2`.